# review low-quality posts presents me with no posts to review despite reporting 45.5k in queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

Attempting to review low-quality posts.

When I first click on the review link, SO tells me there are over 45.5k low-quality posts.

When I click on the low-quality posts link, I am often presented with "no posts to review". Sometimes it presents me with one or two, and then tells me there are no more to review.

I expect this with the suggested edits when there are only 3 or 4 to review. But not with so many low-quality posts.

Are there limits on the number of posts I can review?

Is it possible that are other people simultaneously completing reviews on low-quality posts, and when the system attempts to present me with one and sees that someone else has just completed a review of it, it decides there are no more left and reports that to me instead of moving on to the next one in the queue?

Comment: Until you learn proper English capitalization rules, can you please not review/edit other people's posts?

Comment: all of these off-topic comments aside … i can't use the edit button or fix petty capitalization bugs in other people's low-quality posts because i am seeing buggy behavior whereby the system is telling me there are 45.5k low-quality posts, and then presenting me with none.

Comment: LOL I just had the same thing happen to me!

Comment: Just run out of posts to review, after looking at 3 answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few queries out of wack but a fix has been deployed.  Review on my wayward son.

Comment: indeed, this morning, it seems to be giving me item after item to review.  thanks!